# What's an Application layer?

Tags: layer

I think I understand business logic layer and data access layer, but what is meant by the term application layer? Is it something you use in distributed applications?

Comment: Application Layer[or Service Layer]: Defines the jobs the software is supposed to do and directs the expressive domain objects to work out problems. Responsible for are meaningful to the business or necessary for interaction with the application layers of other systems. Layer is kept thin. Does not contain business rules or knowledge, only coordinates tasks and delegates work to collaborations of domain objects in the next layer down. Does not have state reflecting the business situation, but it can have state that reflects the progress of a task for the user or the program. (Eric Evan's book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the project which is unique for the actual application.

Comment: As opposed to the part that consists of the frameworks that you use.

Comment: "The part of the project which is unique for the actual application."
I thought that's how you define business layer, where the specific logic that governs your application lives.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Layer

In TCP/IP, the Application Layer contains all protocols and methods that fall into the realm of process-to-process communications via an Internet Protocol (IP) network using the Transport Layer protocols to establish underlying host-to-host connections.

In the OSI model, the definition of its Application Layer is narrower in scope, distinguishing explicitly additional functionality above the Transport Layer at two additional levels: Session Layer and Presentation Layer. OSI specifies strict modular separation of functionality at these layers and provides protocol implementations for each layer.

The common application layer services provide semantic conversion between associated application processes. Note: Examples of common application services of general interest include the virtual file, virtual terminal, and job transfer and manipulation protocols.

Answer (score 0):

An Application layer is a more abstract defination that can be a combination of busines logic and database connection.

You can adapt a application layer within web applications that can be written to take advantage of COM+ services, Message Queuing, directory services, and security services.

Comment: "combination of business logic and database connection."
You've used business layer and persistence layer.
So, is it some interface that an application exposes so that the application can be used without the presentation layer, like maybe write a web service for it?